# testing fixed effect interaction in mixed model (matrix computation)

Tags: mixed-model, maximum-likelihood, matrix

I am fitting mixed model with **X** fixed effect design matrix **Z** is random effect design matrix.

Consider the mixed model:

E[y|u] = **X** $\beta$ + **Z**u

with E[u] = 0,

y ~ (**X**$\beta$, **ZDZ'** + **R**), var(u) = **D**

V = var(y) = **ZDZ'** + **R**

We take y to be normally distributed:

y ~  N(**X** $\beta$, **V**),

***estimating fixed effects for V known***

According to McCulloch and Searle ( [Generalized, Linear and Mixed models book, page 163](https://books.google.com.mx/books?id=kyvgyK_sBlkC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false))

[image]

[image]

To test the null hypothesis H0 : **S'X** $\beta$ = m, where **S'** is of full row rank (rs < rx), we can derive a chi-square statistic using

[image]

Under HQ, $\chi$ 2 has a central $\chi$ 2 distribution with rs = rank(**S**) degrees of freedom.

And F test for fixed effects is:
[image]

Under the null hypothesis, F has an F-distribution on rs and N — rx
degrees of freedom.The null hypothesis is rejected at significance
level a when F exceeds F N-rx, 1- $\alpha$ .

When I have single X variable, F test is strait forward as this include main effect only. **In my case I have two X variables and want to test significance of both X variables and interactions.** How can I achieve this ?

Comment: What do your variables look like? Are they binary? Is your interaction term a simple product like this?
    
       $$ 
  \begin{bmatrix}
x & y & interaction\\
        1 & 6 & 6\\
        2 & 7 & 14\\
        3 & 8 & 24 
  \end{bmatrix}
 $$

Comment: that is categorical ( more than two options) or quantitative as you said

Comment: Wouldn't the coefficient of the product of both X variables count as an interaction term?

Comment: @Digio YES but F test will test variable X1 + X2 + X1*X2 , I need separate tests for X1, X2 and interactions (X1 * X2).

Comment: hi John. Normally I would fit two models (ML), one including all three variables (X1 X2 and X1*X2) and one not, and do the F test for model A vs B. You probably know that. From your comment I see that you want to test for the variables separately? In that case I would first model all three (X1 X2 X1*X2). If the interaction is not significant, you can go on testing without interaction X1 and X2 as usual (either alone or by F test together). If the interaction is significant you should probably really test them together. Hope this helps and interesting if you have different opinions!